# How to test if a dictionary contains certain keys

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a nice approach to test if a dictionary contains multiple keys?

A short version of:

```
d = {}
if 'a' in d and 'b' in d and 'c' in d:
    pass #do something
```

Thanks.

Edit: I can only use python2.4 -.-

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `set.issubset(...)`, like so:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> set(['a', 'b']).issubset(d)
True
>>> set(['a', 'x']).issubset(d)
False
```

---

Python 3 has introduced a set literal syntax which has been backported to Python 2.7, so these days the above can be written:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> {'a', 'b'}.issubset(d)
True
>>> {'a', 'x'}.issubset(d)
False
```

Comment: set(sub_dict).issubset(parent_dict) seems to work too, and it's more simple to me. But thanks for the pointer :)

Answer (score 21):

```
if all(test in d for test in ('a','b','c')):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 6):

In Python3 you can write

```
set("abc")<=d.keys()
```

In Python2.7 you can write

```
d.viewkeys()>=set("abc")
```

of course if the keys are not single chars you can replace
`set("abc")` with `set(('a', 'b', 'c'))`

Comment: would be sweet, but i can only use python 2.4 on our prod server.

Comment: +1 for completeness in case someone later on is looking here and is using python 2.7+

Answer (score 1):

Could use an itemgetter wrapped in a try / except.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d = dict(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
>>> e = dict(a=1,b=2,c=3,e=4)
>>> getter=itemgetter('a','b','c','d')
>>> getter(d)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> getter(e)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'd'
```

But actually I prefer Paul McGuire's solution

Answer (score 1):

In 2.4, I always use set operations for such purposes.  If it's worth a warning (or other kind of msg or exception) when some expected keys are missing, in particular, I do:

```
missing = set(d).difference(('a', 'b', 'c'))
if missing:
    logging.warn("Missing keys: %s", ', '.join(sorted(missing)))
else:
    ...
```

replacing the `logging.warn` call as appropriate, of course (maybe just logging.info or even logging.debug, maybe logging.error, maybe an exception).

The `sorted` part is mostly cosmetic (I like reliable, repeatable error messages) but also helps a bit with testing (when I mock up logging.warn -- or whatever -- in the tests, it's nice to be able to expect a specific string, and if I didn't sort the `missing` set the warning string might vary, of course, since sets, like dicts, don't have a concept of order).