# Test if dict contained in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Testing for equality works fine like this for python dicts:

```
first  = {"one":"un", "two":"deux", "three":"trois"}
second = {"one":"un", "two":"deux", "three":"trois"}

print(first == second) # Result: True
```

But now my second dict contains some additional keys I want to ignore:

```
first  = {"one":"un", "two":"deux", "three":"trois"}
second = {"one":"un", "two":"deux", "three":"trois", "foo":"bar"}
```

**Is there a simple way to test if the first dict is part of the second dict, with all its keys and values?**

**EDIT 1:**

This question is suspected to be a duplicate of [How to test if a dictionary contains certain *keys*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415347/how-to-test-if-a-dictionary-contains-certain-keys), but I'm interested in testing keys *and their values*. Just containing the same keys does not make two dicts equal.

**EDIT 2:**

OK, I got some answers now using four different methods, and proved all of them working. As I need a fast process, I tested each for execution time. I created three identical dicts with 1000 items, keys and values were random strings of length 10. The `second` and `third` got some extra key-value pairs, and the last non-extra key of the `third` got a new value. So, `first` is a subset of `second`, but not of `third`. Using module `timeit` with 10000 repetitions, I got:

```
Method                                                      Time [s]   
first.viewitems() <=second.viewitems()                           0.9 
set(first.items()).issubset(second.items())                      7.3
len(set(first.items()) & set(second.items())) == len(first)      8.5
all(first[key] == second.get(key, sentinel) for key in first)    6.0
```

I guessed the last method is the slowest, but it's on place 2. 
But method 1 beats them all.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test if a dictionary contains certain keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415347/how-to-test-if-a-dictionary-contains-certain-keys)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Check if one dictionary is a subset of another larger dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323749/python-check-if-one-dictionary-is-a-subset-of-another-larger-dictionary)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use a [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

```
# Python 2
if first.viewitems() <= second.viewitems():
    # true only if `first` is a subset of `second`

# Python 3
if first.items() <= second.items():
    # true only if `first` is a subset of `second`
```

Dictionary views are the [standard in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), in Python 2 you need to prefix the standard methods with `view`. They act like sets, and `<=` tests if one of those is a subset of (or is equal to) another.

Demo in Python 3:

```
>>> first  = {"one":"un", "two":"deux", "three":"trois"}
>>> second = {"one":"un", "two":"deux", "three":"trois", "foo":"bar"}
>>> first.items() <= second.items()
True
>>> first['four'] =  'quatre'
>>> first.items() <= second.items()
False
```

This works for *non-hashable values too*, as the keys make the key-value pairs unique already. The documentation is a little confusing on this point, but even with mutable values (say, lists) this works:

```
>>> first_mutable = {'one': ['un', 'een', 'einz'], 'two': ['deux', 'twee', 'zwei']}
>>> second_mutable = {'one': ['un', 'een', 'einz'], 'two': ['deux', 'twee', 'zwei'], 'three': ['trois', 'drie', 'drei']}
>>> first_mutable.items() <= second_mutable.items()
True
>>> first_mutable['one'].append('ichi')
>>> first_mutable.items() <= second_mutable.items()
False
```

You could also use the [`all()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) with a generator expression; use `object()` as a sentinel to detect missing values concisely:

```
sentinel = object()
if all(first[key] == second.get(key, sentinel) for key in first):
    # true only if `first` is a subset of `second`
```

but this isn't as readable and expressive as using dictionary views.

Answer (score 7):

```
all(k in second and second[k] == v for k, v in first.items())
```

if you know that none of the values can be `None`, it will simplify to:

```
all(second.get(k, None) == v for k, v in first.items())
```

Comment: Why did you remove the alternative version you posted earlier? `not (set(first.items()) - set(second.items()))`

Comment: @Iskren because it will not work if values are not hashable, for example if  `'foo':[1, 2, 3]` was one of the items.

Comment: Your second solution is very elegant, though it might get slow if values are deeply nested. Nevertheless it's highly polymorphic and concise. +1

Answer (score 4):

So, you basically want to check if one dictionary is a subset of another.

```
first  = {"one":"un", "two":"deux", "three":"trois"}
second = {"one":"un", "two":"deux", "three":"trois", "foo":"bar"}

def subset_dic(subset, superset):
    return len(set(subset.items()) & set(superset.items())) == len(subset)


print(subset_dic(first, second))
```

Prints:

```
True
```

In case you want to abstract out the subset/superset part:

```
def subset_dic(dict1, dict2):
    return len(set(dict1.items()) & set(dict2.items())) == len(min((dict1, dict2), key=len))
```

**Note**: this will fail to work, if any value is a mutable object. Hence you can add an additional step (convert mutable object to immutable analog) in the function to overcome this limitation.

Comment: Creating a set of both full dictionaries seems a bit expensive.

Comment: Comparing two sets of tuples without hashing is even more expensive in terms of sheer complexity.

Comment: Yes, but no need to compare tuples; dictionaries already have O(1) item access, so you can just iterate through one dictionary and do member checks on the other one.

Comment: There already is an answer that does that and SO rules recommend to post original answers only :)

Comment: Sure, my comment wasn’t meant to be a “this is bad, you should do X instead”, just a general note on the performance of this solution :)

Answer (score 4):

**# Updated Ans:**

**METHOD-1: Using Dictionary Views:**

As [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) suggested, We can use dictionary views to check this. `dict.viewitems()` acts as a set. We can perform various set operations on this like intersection, union etc. (Check this [link](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).)

```
first.viewitems() <= second.viewitems()
True
```

We check if `first` is less than equal to `second`. This evaluating to True means `first` is a subset of `second.`

**METHOD-2 Using issubset() operation of sets:**

**(DISCLAIMER: This method has some redundancy and requires all values to be hashable. Method-1 is suggested to be followed to handle all cases. Thanks [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) for the suggestions.)**

Use `.items()` attribute of a dictionary to get a list of (key,value) tuples and then use **issubset()** operation of sets.

**This will check for both the keys and the equality.**.

```
>>> first  = {"one":"un", "two":"deux", "three":"trois"}
>>> second = {"one":"un", "two":"deux", "three":"trois", "foo":"bar"}

>>> set(first.items()).issubset(second.items())
True
```

Comment: Why use `list()` first and not use `set(first.items()).issubset(second.items())` directly? And in Python 3, `dict.items()` *supports the usecase directly*; `l1.items() < l2.items()` works just fine. Note that this requires all values to be hashable (using `set()` objects or dictionary views).

Comment: Thanks Martijn. That step was unnecessary. Updated the ans!

Comment: You still have redundancy here; in Python 3 `dict.items()` *already acts as a set*. In Python 2 you can get the same behaviour by using `dict.viewitems()`. And your approach still requires that the values are hashable, while dictionary views do not.

Comment: Yeaa updated! thanks for the suggestions Martijn..:)